# Use of AX 2012 debugger when other users also work on same ax client

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I would like to debug code in PreProduction environment but I'm wondering if it will bother other users who are using same AX client. Will it affect others if I debug code?

Answer (score 2):

It should not bother other users since the debugger is a program separate to the client.

Add breakpoints to the code using F9, or selecting Toggle breakpoint in the debug menu or clicking on the gray line next to the code. The breakpoint is then user specific and the client will only stop and start debugging for your user.

If you set a breakpoint in your X++ code by using the breakpoint statement, that will bother users and when their actions reach the breakpoint statement, the client will stop and start a debugging session.

So use this:

[image]

And not this:

[image]

Comment: But what I think is when debugger is opened we can not do anything in AX client right? So maybe we can't be 100% sure as client and debugger are in the same process

Comment: When you are debugging, you cannot do any action in the client until you have finished debugging, but other users can work normally with their clients. If you access a record while debugging, and another user access the same record, you will most likely have same result as if you both access the record at the same time and you were not using the debugger.

Comment: Beware that transactions takes longer to complete when debugged! This may show up as hangs for other users until the debug session is stopped by shift-F5 or it has passed the last `ttscommit`.

Comment: You could block users because you are keeping certain locks in the database for to long.

Answer (score 2):

It will most likely **not** disrupt users in the way you think it may.  Like Jan said, their clients could hang, but when your client is frozen during debugging, their clients will not be frozen at the same time, merely because you are debugging. They open their own sessions and connect to the AOS independently of each other. They would be affected by locked transactions, that should take seconds, but since you've potentially paused code execution in the middle of a transaction, it will maintain a lock.

You can demonstrate this by debugging in a development environment, then opening a second client instance on the same local or on a remote machine, and you will see that you can continue working/testing.  This is what you should do if you are very concerned about impact.

If they have administrative or AX debugger permissions on the machine, global breakpoints turned on, and the debugger installed in tandem with the client where they are working, then technically they could launch a debugger session...but the planets sort of have to align for that to happen in most installations. It would be very bad practice for that to happen.